# Is there a shortcut to retrieve the angle of an arc of an ellipse, just using its legth?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, ellipse

I had no clue ellipses had such math entry level requirements...

I'm wondering if there is a shortcut to get the angle of an elliptical arc from it's length and 2 radius?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closed formula for ellipse arc length, so there is no reverse formula to obtain angle from length and ellipse semiaxes. Moreover, length/angle ration varies depending on starting angle.

If starting angle is fixed, you can use numerical methods to find need angle:
[calculate value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) of integral

```
 Len(X) = Int[t=t0..X]{Sqrt(a^2 * Sin^2(t) + b^2 * Cos^2(t))}
```

for some initial approximation of X. If Len is too large, divide angle interval by 2 and check again, if too small - enlarge it ([bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or another [root-finding technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm)). Repeat while error becomes small enough.

Comment: Thank you sir.

I have no idea what is an integral or closed formula. Much reading to do.

Cheers